# how to determine the storage layout of a contract programmatically

Tags: solidity, storage

It's easy enough to grab the data at any storage location of a contract, but we need to know the state variable declarations/storage layout of the contract to know what we're doing and how to interpret the data.

How can I **programmatically** find out the state variable declarations/storage layout for a contract?

I'd like to make a storage explorer type tool and being able to determine the storage layout of a contract is a game changer.

Comment: Well, any contact published on the network should have it's code public, and from there (its code) you should be able to understand it's storage layout. Right?

Comment: that is a manual process, not determining the storage layout **programmatically**. A tool would be even more useful if it could figure out the storage layout for a contract **didn't** have the contacts source code available

Comment: Hmm, it should be possible (after all , the code published on Blockchain is publicly available). But I had heard of no tool that can do that. Good question.

Comment: It does not satisfy all the requirements (needs the contract source), but it may be helpful nonetheless: https://github.com/tintinweb/smart-contract-inspector

Comment: You could also pretty easily write a script to read all the transactions made to a contract and play all the storage events.

Answer (score 4):

If a contract is written in Solidity entirely, then it should follow the [storage layout rules](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/internals/layout_in_storage.html). We can implement the logic ourselves, or use the output from solc:

```
% solc --storage-layout /tmp/A.sol | tail -1 | jq .
{
  "storage": [
    {
      "astId": 4,
      "contract": "/tmp/A.sol:A",
      "label": "x",
      "offset": 0,
      "slot": "0",
      "type": "t_uint64"
    },
    {
      "astId": 7,
      "contract": "/tmp/A.sol:A",
      "label": "y",
      "offset": 8,
      "slot": "0",
      "type": "t_uint128"
    },
```

A decompiler might be helpful if the source is not available.

If the author uses assembly / inline assembly, then the contract  may not follow any layout rules. For example,

```
PUSH1 42
TIMESTAMP
SSTORE
```

this code will write 42 to the storage slot pointed by the timestamp.

Comment: I tried to run this command and it gives me an error `unrecognised option '--storage-layout' `. I ran it without the tail command as a I am on windows. Is there any other way you can suggest?? for windows